# Error initializating SparkContext with "spark-shell --master yarn-client", just "spark-shell" works fine

Tags: apache-spark

I have a single node with hadoop cluster running and now Im trying to start spark with yarn. Im starting spark like this `spark-shell --master yarn-client`, but Im getting this error below. For spark I just download, extract and configure the spark-env.sh file, and start all spark processes like this:

```
SPARK_JAVA_OPTS=-Dspark.driver.port=53411
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.1/etc/hadoop
SPARK_MASTER_IP=master
```

And then I start all processes of spark with `

```
./start-all.sh
```

Do you have any idea why this error can be happening?

Error:

```
16/05/14 00:26:10 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after waiting maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime: 30000(ms)
16/05/14 00:26:10 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:584)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
        at $line3.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:26)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:30)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
16/05/14 00:26:10 INFO spark.SparkContext: SparkContext already stopped.
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:584)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
        at <init>(<console>:26)
        at .<init>(<console>:30)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$.createListenerAndUI(SQLContext.scala:1367)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:1028)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:24)
        at <init>(<console>:26)
        at .<init>(<console>:30)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.implicits._
                ^
<console>:16: error: not found: value sqlContext
         import sqlContext.sql
```

If I start spark with just `spark-shell` it works fine, sql context is initialized.

yarn-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>master:8031</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>master:8032</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>master:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
<value>master:8033</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
<value>master:8088</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Jps Command:

```
id ResourceManager
id RunJar
id SecondaryNameNode
id DataNode
id NodeManager
id Jps
id NameNode
```

Additional error with spark debug mode on:

```
16/05/14 18:06:48 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (1374243709) connection to master/10.10.0.11:8032 from hadoopadmin: closed
16/05/14 18:06:48 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (1374243709) connection to master/10.10.0.11:8032 from hadoopadmin: stopped, remaining connections 1
16/05/14 18:06:48 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (1374243709) connection to master/10.10.0.11:9000 from hadoopadmin: closed
16/05/14 18:06:48 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (1374243709) connection to master/10.10.0.11:9000 from hadoopadmin: stopped, remaining connections 0
16/05/14 18:06:49 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after waiting maxRegisteredResourcesWaitingTime: 30000(ms)
16/05/14 18:06:49 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Sorry, but I m  little confused to understand what are you trying to do here? start spark standalone cluster? or just using spark with yarn?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Im trying to run spark on top of my single node hadoop cluster that is already running, using yarn as Spark resource manager.

Comment: so there is no need to set SPARK_MASTER_IP (as the master is yarn) neither to start spark process by `./sbin/start-all.sh`

Comment: Hm, I will try without that. But the other configs SPARK_JAVA_OPTS and HADOOP_CONF_DIR, are needed?

Comment: could you paste the output of `$ jps` here? I doubt that there is some processes missing, maybe there is no nodemanagers running.

Comment: `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` is needed, but the conf in `SPARK_JAVA_OPTS` is optional, actually if you haven't set the driver port, spark is intelligent enough to pick an available port for the driver

Comment: Thanks, but without that confs, only with HADOOP_CONF_DIR I get the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111918/discussion-between-user1314742-and-codin).

Answer (score 0):

Similar exception is thrown when YARN Resource Manager/Node Manager is unable to start a dedicated container for Spark. There is a good chance that it is related to resource allocation (memory/CPU). Check logs in the *$HADOOP_HOME/logs*. If node manager fails due to the lack of resources, you should find an error/warn message in node manager logs.